# how I can make date control (after date - before date) in laravel 5

Tags: date, laravel, laravel-request

Hi I want to make after date-before date control that is using request validation in laravel.
So, starting date should not be  more than end date. how can do this. I would appreciate if you could help me.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
         'start_date' =>'required|date_format:d.m.Y',
         'end_date'   =>'required|date_format:d.m.Y',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it in this way.

```
public function rules()

{
    return [

         'start_date =>'required|date_format:d.m.Y',
         'end_date' =>'required|date_format:d.m.Y|after:start_date'       
 ];

}
```